# java program freezes when calling another program in same jar

Tags: java

I just wanted to add space invaders as an easter egg to a program I made.
I found an open source code [Here](http://www.cokeandcode.com/info/tut2d.html)

The game runs fine on its own. However when I try to run it from a button in my program it makes my program and that game freeze. I just took his source code and added it to mine, so it is in the same jar file.

I tried 2 ways to start it.

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {         
                Game.main(null);
                }
        });           
        }
```

and

plain old `Game.main(null);`

Should I be starting this some other way?

Comment: No, kind of should just work. Check if your main method is happy enough with null as parameter. Any error messages?

Comment: Well if we don't know in which environment you are (like knowing if your application has a GUI) we won't be able to help you.

Comment: It does start the space invaders but they both freeze. I have a gui in both. In terms of environment its windows 7 with java 7.

Comment: Does Game extend JFrame or anything? If you have access to the game's main class could you not just use `new Game().setVisible(true);`?

Comment: tried that dosn't work. the gameloop is actually needed to start the program. i was hoping to avoid programming a space invaders myself, just wanted a simple easter egg. something is getting stuck because they are both running at the same time from the same jar.

Comment: also it will only accept null and not args. not sure why.

Comment: If your program is "freezing", you could use jstack (a program provided by java) to determine what line it is stuck on.  Then you could find your problem more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main() {  

        // Start the main game loop, note: this method will not
        // return until the game has finished running. Hence we are
        // using the actual main thread to run the game.    
        SpaceInvaders si = new SpaceInvaders();
        Thread SpaceInvaders = new Thread(si);
        SpaceInvaders.start();          
        }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new SpaceInvaders().gameLoop();
    }
}
```

Just had to create it's own thread for it.